# Matrix notation and multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, markov-chains

I have a question regarding the index set notation for matrices.
Let $Q$ be a matrix indexed by $\{0,1\}^N\times\{0,1\}^N$ that is for $n,m\in \{0,1\}^N$ we can define $Q(n,m)\in\mathbb{R}$. How can I now write down matrix vector multiplication?
In particular let $G:\{0,1\}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function how do I interpret $QG(n)$?
For example in the case $G(n)=n_i$, i.e. coordinate projection to the $i$-the coordinate the formula is supposed to be
$$QG(n)=\sum_mQ(n,m)m_i$$
I don't understand this formula at all and can't think of this "multidimensional" matrix notation in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is indexed by sets $I,J$ and $B$ is indexed by $J,K$, then the product $AB$ of these matrices is indexed by $I,K$ with entries defined by
$$
[AB](i,k) = \sum_{j \in J} A(i,j)B(j,k).
$$
With that said, we will have
$$
[QG](n) = \sum_{m \in \{0,1\}^N}Q(n,m)G(m).
$$